# To (sb) I will be talking to...(grammar)

Tags: grammar

> I have to learn as many English words as I can, and to use them whenever I need them to be clearly understood, especially **to individuals whom I will be talking to.**

Are the bold letters grammatical?

Comment: It should be "**are** the bold letters grammatical" because we're asking about an adjective, which is something they are, not a verb, which is something they do.

Comment: Adjective phrase you are saying? I'll edit this also...

Comment: What makes you think the highlighted portion isn't grammatical? Highlighting a few words isn't exactly what the guidance means by "focusing on something in particular". Are you concerned about the use of "will be"? "Whom"? Something else?

Comment: The answers that had been provided here before yours are what I really need, coz it sounds a bit awkward to ear if I ever use the bold letters in future conversations if they were not corrected beforehand, as I am not sure if I were expressing myself clearly, also to avoid misinterpretations or any sort. I just have to make sure what I will say, in the future, is crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three alternatives to form a subordinate clause with a relative pronoun and preposition. As follows:

> This is the topic **about which** I don't want to talk.
>
> This is the topic **which** I don't want to talk **about**.
>
> This is the topic I don't want to talk **about**.

In the third sentence the relative pronoun is omitted because **to talk about something** goes with a direct object hand in hand, and in that special case the RP can undergo omission.

> I don't know the guy **(-)** I saw last day talking to you in the hallway.

As we see, the position of the *pre*position in a sentence can vary, however, in your sentence I don't see any cohesion between *to* (the word that opens the SC) and the main clause.

> I **have to learn** (predicate 1/I) as many English words as I can, and to **use** (predicate 1/II) them whenever I **need** (predicate 1/III) them to be clearly understood, *especially* (here we expect a Verb (when it comes to...) or a Prepositional (in case of emergency, for example) Phrase to come up on the horizon of this sentence) **to individuals** (it is a Prepositional Phrase, but it is totally incoherent) whom I **will be talking** to (predicate 2/I).

The problem of the subordinate clause is that the preposition refers to the verb (to talk *to* somebody) which is free from the content of the main clause. On the other hand, *to* is kind of out of context here. I would advise you to use the following sentence as a replacement:

> ...especially in conversation with individuals to whom I will be talking.

Answer (score 1):

It is ungrammatical and awkward.

"need them to be understood **by**" is the grammatical preposition to use to indicate the active agent in a passive construction.

"**whom** I will be talking **to**" is grammatical (unless you insist on the now rare distinction between "will" and "shall"), but it is a bit awkward.

Better would be "**to whom I will** be talking" or "**to whom I shall** be talking."

Comment: Totally agree that it's awkward. Even better might be: "...especially to individuals I will be talking with". (I don't see any need for the "to whom" at all, and _with_ seems like a better option than _to_.)

Comment: What is the key thing in good speaking anyway? Not to sound awkward or the like?

Comment: The key thing is to be understood. Grammar is one way to avoid misunderstanding. When we say something is awkward but grammatical, we simply mean that there is a grammatical way to convey the same sense with a somewhat lower probability of confusing the listener or reader. Lazy writers complain without warrant about their readers being lazy when there is a misunderstanding. It is silly for me to complain that others are too lazy to accommodate my laziness. The question is not what I meant, but rather how clearly did I express what I meant.

Comment: @JeffMorrow In US engineering contracts and specifications the "will" and "shall" distinction is still alive and well.

Comment: @m_a_s It is a useful distinction. The problem with purely descriptive grammar is that it encourages the loss of important tools of language.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: How about this: "I have to learn as many English words as I can, and to use them whenever I need them to be clearly understood by individuals whom I will be talking". Is it grammatical and not awkward-sounding now?

Comment: No it is not grammatical. It is not idiomatic. **Talk** in the sense that you are using it must be used as a compound verb with either **to** or **with**. JR seems to feel that **with** is more idiomatic. I do not agree, but JR is certainly right, according to ngram, that **talk with** is more frequent  than **talk to**.